# Is any image link suitable for suitable for adding in html file?

Tags: html, css, web

I know I can add images to a html file by the following syntax

```
<img src="*****">
```

But my question is can i copy any images link from the web and add them to my html file?
i'm not talking about the copyright laws regarding this, just, can every image link be used as the image source in html?
I was writing a code in codepen where i embedded a link to an image from devianart, but the image didn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i find on **W3schools**:

**Definition and Usage:**

The required src attribute specifies the URL of the image.

Note: When a web page loads; it is the browser, at that moment, that gets the image from a web server and inserts it into the page. Therefore, make sure that the image actually stay in the same spot in relation to the web page, otherwise your visitors will get a broken link icon. The broken link icon is shown if the browser cannot find the image.

The URL of the image.
Possible values:

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
  src="http://www.example.com/image.gif")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like
  src="image.gif")

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends to the website policy; Some websites don't let you to use their hosted images in your webpage, and some others do.

Answer (score 0):

make sure image fully open in your browser tab/
 i also check it but it work in codepen may be you doing something wrong first need to write clear what you  want
try this image tag in codepen